# Referencing a variable within another variable

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out the correct syntax or function to use to reference a variable from another variable. For example,

```
    $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar' ;
    $var1 = '$_SESSION[\'foo\']' ;
    $var2 = ${"$var1"} ;
    echo "$var2" ;
```

How do I get to display the value 'bar'?

Comment: $var1 = &$var1 from what I remember

Comment: You want the value of the session var into `$var1`?   You're overcomplicating things: `$var1 = $_SESSION['foo'];` There's no need for [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) if this is just a simple assignment.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski He doesn't want to assign it, he wants to reference it

Comment: @meanIOstack I'm not certain of that - the question isn't clear enough and occam's razor etc...

Comment: Do you want to be able to modify `$_SESSION['foo']` and have that automatically appear in `$var1`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski e clearly said reference, not assign. Barmar is getting the idea

Comment: Yes I want reference it.  `$var1` is being pulled from a database as to which variable to display.  So if I want to display 'bar', I would like to put the reference of '$_SESSION[\'foo\']' so that I can dynamic display the variable I want

Comment: @meanIOstack Just because he said it doesn't mean he really wants that. If he's a PHP newbie, he probably doesn't know what a reference is.

Comment: If he is using sessions, I'm sure he knows how to assign a variable

Comment: `$var2 = $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';` Now they're both `'bar'`.

Comment: Yeah but he is referencing a session as a string and not the global...

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: What op wants to do is: use the string `'$_SESSION[\'foo\']'` to get the value of `$_SESSION['foo']`, it's not referencing but something of eval.

Comment: In that case what he wants IS `eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a reference variable:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
$var1 = $_SESSION['foo'];
$var2 = &$_SESSION['foo'];
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'abc';

echo $var1; // prints bar
echo $var2; // prints abc
```

Or maybe this is what you want:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
$var1 = '$_SESSION[\'foo\']';
$var2 = eval("return $var1;"); // The argument to eval has to be a statement
echo $var2; // prints bar
```

Comment: What op wants to do is: use the string `'$_SESSION[\'foo\']'` to get the value of `$_SESSION['foo']`, it's not referencing but something of eval.

Comment: I've added an `eval` solution.

Comment: I forgot about `ob_start()`.

Comment: No idea what `ob_start()` has to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

To reference a variable use the ampersand `&` before the variable like so:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar' ;
$var1 = '$_SESSION[\'foo\']' ;
$var2 = &$var1;
echo "$var2" ;
```

Comment: `$var2 = &$var1;` is not going to `eval()` the `$_SESSION['foo']` here, it's just a string literal in `$var1`.

Comment: That's what he wants, it seems

Comment: This gives me `$_SESSION['foo']` not `bar`.

Comment: Yes. but I now want to reference the value of $var1.  I've tried eval() but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: just wondering, do you know the difference between refrencing and assignment?

Comment: Yes, I believe know the diff between referencing and assigning.  $var1 is being assigned with value of ''$_SESSION[\'foo\']'.  and I want to reference it so that I eventually get 'bar'.  I may be mixing my terminologies here.

Comment: why not just get it from `$_SESSION['foo']`. What's the point of going through the `$var1`?